# Get results from querying .xml file

Tags: xml

So I have this question on how to get some results from a .xml file.
We are comparing 2 versions of our program by generating an xml file with al the differences for multiple files with the structure:

```
<Results>
   <ElemXDataList>
    <Item From="0" To="10" Elements="14511"> 
     <ElemXData>
      <Item>
       <Line>1</Line>
       <Col>0</Col>
       <Header>ID</Header>
       <Val1>0</Val1>
       <Val2>0</Val2>
       <Percent>0</Percent>
      </Item>
      <Item>
       ...
      </Item>
       ...
     </ElemXData>
     </Items>
    <Item From="10" To="20" Elements="1095">
     ...
    </Item>
    ...
   </ElemXDataList>
</Results>
```

The first tag item has the differences from 0 to 10 with 14511 items, the second one has 1095 items with differences between 10 and 20..and so one, the limits can be modified in the meantime but you get the point. 
This will be a final .xml file for multiple files (there will be item tag with the same limit but with different number of elements, depending how many differ) or maybe different .xml files and query them all from a path.
I want to lighten the task of the testers (they don't have a background in programming) so they'll have a point to start where to look and give them 3 fields with the limits "From" and "To" and another with the limit for the number of elements. The results for now will be true or false, in the future I'll return a more detailed summary.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve this or maybe something to start with? I'm a c++ programmer with some experience in C#.
Thank you for the time in reading this long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try XML Linq like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<Results>" +
                  "<ElemXDataList>" +
                    "<Item From=\"0\" To=\"10\" Elements=\"14511\">" +
                      "<ElemXData>" +
                        "<Item>" +
                          "<Line>1</Line>" +
                          "<Col>0</Col>" +
                          "<Header>ID</Header>" +
                          "<Val1>0</Val1>" +
                          "<Val2>0</Val2>" +
                          "<Percent>0</Percent>" +
                        "</Item>" +
                        "<Item>" +
                        "</Item>" +
                      "</ElemXData>" +
                    "</Item>" +
                    "<Item From=\"10\" To=\"20\" Elements=\"1095\">" +
                    "</Item>" +
                  "</ElemXDataList>" +
                "</Results>";

            XElement results = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var elemXDataList = results.Descendants("ElemXDataList").FirstOrDefault().Elements("Item").Select(x => new
            {
                from = (int)x.Attribute("From"),
                to = (int)x.Attribute("To"),
                elements = (int)x.Attribute("Elements"),
                children = x.FirstNode
            }).ToList();

            var query = elemXDataList.Where(x => (x.from == 0) && (x.to == 10) && (x.elements == 14511)).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thank you @dweng for the detailed answer, I'll start working based on this.

Comment: Just a question, how do I query the "elemXDataList" usinq Linq for let's say from 20 to 25 with a maxim of 50 elements?

Comment: nvm, I figured out, I used "var result = elemXDataList.Where(el => 
                (el.from == 20 && el.to == 25 && el.elements < 100)).ToList();"

Comment: I updated question.  I would use FirstOrDefault() instead of list.

Answer (score 0):

For a lightweight C++ implementation/example see below.
This is using the free opensource pugixml library that can be downloaded from http://pugixml.org/

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    if (!doc.load_file("/path/filename.xml")) return -1;

    pugi::xpath_query query_tool("//Item");
    pugi::xpath_node_set tools = query_tool.evaluate_node_set(doc);
    pugi::xpath_query query_From("@From");
    pugi::xpath_query query_To("@To");
    pugi::xpath_query query_Elements("@Elements");

    for (pugi::xml_node tool = tools.first().node(); tool; tool = tool.next_sibling())
    {
        std::string f = query_From.evaluate_string(tool);
        std::string t = query_To.evaluate_string(tool);
        std::string e = query_Elements.evaluate_string(tool);
        std::cout << f << ", " << t << ", " << e << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is good to know, I'll take a look at it. A nice day to you sir.